# Command button on core form creating wrong record

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

i created one table measurePerVolume, and add that in a core form, i created one tab with one grid inside, and put actionPane, button group and command button (command: new) all of them with my datasource, but when run that, command button try to create a record in inventTable insted mine.

I tried build model again but i really don't have idea what happening here

that table have many to one in inventTable.

Comment: element's with right datasource: https://imgur.com/a/ke2RRnR

Comment: Few things to check: Is your primary/first datasource in the datasource list the inventtable? If so, make your custom table the primary datasource and join inventtable to it instead (also make sure relations and foreign keys are setup correctly in at the table level). Also, check the button group's datasource is set to your table.